# Is evince-gtk protected by apparmor?

Tags: evince, apparmor

The 14.10 software center offers `evince` and a version called `evince-gtk` with fewer GNOME dependencies.

In `/etc/apparmor.d` there is an apparmor profile for `evince`: `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.evince`. My question is this: will this profile also protect `evince-gtk`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The evince-gtk package [installs its executable as /usr/bin/evince](http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/amd64/evince-gtk/filelist), so assuming the AppArmor profile is written conventionally, I think the answer you're looking for is yes.

Just to be clear, though, AppArmor isn't protecting evince. It's protecting you and your system *from* evince.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I'd go further and say that it attempts to  protect me and my system from potential exploits contained in documents opened by evince.

Comment: That too. :) I guess it depends on whether you think someone might slip malicious code into evince, or accidentally include a bug that does damage. Both have been done in other projects.